# Creating multiple variables using multiple variables in SAS

Tags: sql, if-statement, sas, proc-sql

The data is like this.....

```
Line1       Line2       Product_name   Segment 1  Segment 2 

EUCREAS     ORAAL       EUCREAS        DPP-4      DPP-4 -EUCREAS
GALVUS      ORAAL       GALVUS         DPP-4      DPP-4 -GALVUS
GLICLAZIDE  ORAAL       DIAMICRON      SU         SU -GLICLAZIDE
GLICLAZIDE  ORAAL       GLICLAZIDE     SU         SU -GLICLAZIDE
GLP-1       ORAAL       BYDUREON       GLP-1      GLP-1
GLP-1       ORAAL       BYETTA         GLP-1      GLP-1
GLP-1       ORAAL       LYXUMIA        GLP-1      GLP-1
GLP-1       ORAAL       VICTOZA        GLP-1      GLP-1
INSULINES   INSULINES   ACTRAPHANE     INSULINES  INSULINES
INSULINES   INSULINES   ACTRAPID       INSULINES  INSULINES
```

here I have to use `line1`,`line2` and `product_name` to create `segment1` & `segment2`.

I can use if statement but are there any other ways to do this in data step or proc sql.

Comment: Post what you've tried so far and explain your logic. How is Segment1/Segment2 calculated? I could probably make some guesses but it's easier and faster if you explain your problem.

Comment: By using if statement:-- data dsn;

Comment: seg1 and seg2 depends upon certain combination of line1,line2 and product_name. so i used if statementlike this and i got the output.                      data dsn;                                                                                                  set dsn1;  if line1='EUCREAS' and line2='ORAAL' and product_name='EUCREAS' then do;                                                                                         seg1='DPP-4';seg2='DPP-4-EUCREAS';run;. i want to know any shorter way i can do this bcoz it ll b too long to put all the if statements;

Comment: Create a lookup table and join, but no matter what you need to have the information somewhere first, whether you type it out into an IF/THEN statement or if you create it as a data set in SAS or Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a fairly simple mapping from LINE1/LINE2/PRODUCT_NAME to your segments, a nice way to do this is to create a format:

```
proc format;
  value $seg1f
    'EUCREAS:ORAAL:EUCREAS' = 'DPP-4'
    'GALVUS:ORAAL:EUCREAS' = 'DPP-4'
    ....
  ;
  value $seg2f
    'EUCREAS:ORAAL:EUCREAS' = 'DPP-4 - EUCREAS'
    'GALVUS:ORAAL:EUCREAS' = 'DPP-4 - GALVUS'
    ....
  ;
run;
```

You can then just assign:

```
data want;
  set have;
  seg1 = put(catx(':', line1, line2, product_name), $seg1f.);
  seg2 = put(catx(':', line1, line2, product_name), $seg2f.);
run;
```

Or you can use the same formats in a `PROC SQL` step if that's more convenient. You would need to think carefully about the delimiter to use, and you can't call the formats just `seg1` and `seg2` because format names aren't allowed to end with digits. You can create the formats programatically if necessary, see the `CNTLIN` option on `PROC FORMAT`.

Comment: thanks .  but the output is not  correct.here what i did.PROC FORMAT ;
VALUE $SEG112F 'EUCREAS,ORAAL,EUCREAS'='DPP-4';
RUN;    it should show  only one value for  seg1;    but it showing more than one see the output;

Comment: I don't see any output anywhere, can you show it? Assign the result of your CATX function to a temporary variable so that you can see what's being passed in to the format.

Comment: here is the output--                                                                                                                          Line1         Line2 Product_name  SEG1
EUCREAS ORAAL EUCREAS        DPP-4
GALVUS         ORAAL GALVUS                GALVU
GLICLAZIDE ORAAL DIAMICRON       GLICL
GLICLAZIDE ORAAL GLICLAZIDE       GLICL
GLP-1         ORAAL BYDUREON       GLP-1
GLP-1         ORAAL BYETTA               GLP-1
GLP-1         ORAAL LYXUMIA              GLP-1
GLP-1       ORAAL        VICTOZA        GLP-1
INSULINES INSULINES ACTRAPHANE INSU

Comment: The output you've pasted is hard to parse, but it looks like you've just forgotten to set a default length for SEG1 in your data step - all the values are five characters long. Try adding 'length seg1 $ 100;' at the beginning of your data step (I left this out of my example for clarity, but it's needed in real code). It's a good idea to add additional information like this as an edit to your original question, rather than as a comment.

Comment: And another possibility - if you've literally only set one decode value in your format, any input values that aren't known to the format will just be passed through unchanged - you should add an 'other = 'Unknown'' line at the end of your format definition. See http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/70377/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1upn25lbfo6mkn1wncu4dyh9q91.htm

Comment: thanks it worked i put length and other='na'. thank u again. i am new to sas and stack. i am learning .thank u again.